# Django: Pagination without changing url?

Tags: python, html, django, html-table, pagination

I learned the pagination basics for Django from this link:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/03/how-to-paginate-with-django.html

However! the only problem I have is that I want to paginate without changing url.

By that, I mean I need to paginate a table while there are multiple tables in a html page.

How do i paginate only one table???

My code:

This is the basic structure of the html template:

```
                  ...      
                    <table class="uk-table uk-table-striped">
                        <tbody>
                            {% for post_status in post.statusPage %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ post_status.status_time }}</td>
                                <td>{{ post_status.repost_count }}</td>
                                <td>{{ post_status.comment_count }}</td>
                                <td>{{ post_status.like_count }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    {% if post.statusPage.has_other_pages %}
                        <ul class="uk-pagination uk-flex-center" uk-margin>
                            {% if post.statusPage.has_previous %}
                                <li><a href="#"><span uk-pagination-previous></span></a></li>
                            {% else %}
                                <li><a><span uk-pagination-previous></span></a></li>
                            {% endif %}

                            {% for i in post.statusPage.paginator.page_range %}
                                {% if post.statusPage.number == i %}
                                    <li class="uk-active"><span>{{ i }}</span></li>
                                {% else %}
                                    <li><a href="#">{{ i }}</a></li>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% if post.statusPage.has_next %}
                                <li><a href="#"><span uk-pagination-next></span></a></li>
                            {% else %}
                                <li><a><span uk-pagination-next></span></a></li>
                            {% endif %}
                        </ul>
                    {% endif %}
```

In side the template, there are multiple post objects

```
post
```

Each post has its own table and paginator:

```
post.statusPage
```

is the page object of the post.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than building the pagination yourself and dealing with the complexity you're running into, consider using [DataTables](https://datatables.net).

You can place multiple tables on a single view, and the pagination for each table is handled via javascript with no actual change in the URL. You can either insert the values into the table using standard django template tags, or you can build a simple API (using [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org) or django's [JSON](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/serialization/) libraries) to feed the tables via Ajax. This is a bit more advanced, but when you have a lot of data, it ensures you aren't sending it all to the user at once and hogging system memory.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I know what you're trying to do, but it seems like your view returns a full set of tables, and you'd like the user to be able to view them one at a time, with a click in between, instead of scrolling down forever.  You don't want to hit a different URL, so this needs to be handled in the client browser, and that means this is not a Django problem and hence not a Django solution.  (Calling it pagination but also wanting it all to appear at the same URL and hence be the same web page is slightly confusing.)

The simplest way from where you are now might be toggling ['show-hide' html divs](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp), that  with a button created for each page. So each page is rendered but selectively presented. You'd have to modify the little script there to set all other pages to hidden.
I'm sorry I haven't got a better example for your particular situation.  There are probably a bunch of more elegant javascript-heavy solutions out there, but I can't advise you on those.

If you are willing to send querystrings with a Get request for the next page, you could solve this entirely with Django, by creating links that include '?param=' type page numbers. The parameters can then be obtained from '[request.GET.getlist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist)('param')' to return the right page.  But if your view returns everything now, you might not want to get into generating and handling querystrings.